# NullPointerException while reading multiple files from a directory

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

When I run the following piece of code, I'm getting a NullPointerException. This method is used to scan a directory and retrieve all files(.java) in it and then count the NLOC and NLC.

So here is the code :

```
public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines;
    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {  // <<--- exception here
      if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
      } else {
        if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
          temp = fileEntry.getName();
          if ((temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, temp.length()).toLowerCase()).equals("java")) {
            fileName = folder.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileEntry.getName();
            try {
              lines = getLines(fileName);
              totalCommentCount += calcComments(lines);
              totalLOC += calcLOC(lines);

            } catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println("File does not exist!" + e);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.append("Comment Lines :").append(totalCommentCount);
    output.append("\n");
    output.append("Lines of Code (LOC) :").append(totalLOC);
    txtDisplayResults.setText(output.toString());
 }
```

Here is the error message (I use netbeans as the IDE):

```
23-Jul-2013 13:17:53 scaj.GUI listFilesForFolder
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scaj.GUI.listFilesForFolder(GUI.java:61)
    at scaj.GUI.listFilesForFolder(GUI.java:68)
    at scaj.GUI.bScanActionPerformed(GUI.java:326)
    at scaj.GUI.access$100(GUI.java:17)
    at scaj.GUI$2.actionPerformed(GUI.java:235)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: Please debug or tell us the exact line ! `scaj.GUI.listFilesForFolder(GUI.java:61)` ...

Comment: `for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) { `
Is the line causing the NullPointerException

Comment: How is `folder` declared?

Comment: As araknoid wrote... Show us the code where you initiate the folder object.

Comment: I guess it would be better if you would edit your post and add the whole listFilesForFolder()-method so that we can review it.

Comment: The folder is null. Make sure to initialize it. Or it's not a directory.

Comment: I just edited the question and posted the method declaration too.

Comment: `File[] files = folder.listFiles(); if (files != null { for (File fileEntry : files) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`folder.listFiles()` returns null, when folder isn't a directory (which it is in this case) or when an IO error occurs. Is it possible that the web server doesn't have the correct rights to access some folders? Or they are not reachable (they are connected via a network).

Add a nullcheck to `folder.listFiles()` and print out for which folders it returns null. This should help you to determine why it is happening. If you can't find the cause, please add the folders for which it is happening to the question.

Comment: Thank you, I did add the null checker to `folder.listFiles()` and found out the folder causing all the trouble.
I was scanning `C:\Users\UserName\Documents` folder in my local hard disk. 
The following three folders caused the problems.

`1.C:\Users\UserName\Documents\My Music
  2.C:\Users\UserName\Documents\My Pictures
  3.C:\Users\UserName\Documents\My Videos`

Any idea how to skip these folders (which doesn't really exist) ?

Comment: `File[] files = folder.listFiles(); if (files != null) { for (File fileEntry : files) {` did the trick ! 
It is solved now! 
Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

Your folder.listFiles() is returning null. The listFiles() method:

`Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.`