# NullPointerException on accessing Files in folder

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception

I am trying to list the files in a folder but it produces a null pointer exception
this is the code

```
String url=req.getRequestURI();
String path=session.getServletContext().getRealPath(url);
File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {//this line is producing nullpointer exception
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    }
```

When i print the path it gives the correct path:
like `D:\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\webapps\JaasLogin\JaasLogin\user-files`.
i am new to java 
Context path: /jaasLogin
but when i give path directly like  `"D:\\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\\webapps\\JaasLogin\\JaasLogin\\user-files"` it will works

Output i got

```
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [userfileserv] in context with path [/JaasLogin] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myPackage.UserFileServ.doGet(UserFileServ.java:31)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
```

Comment: Please edit the `NullPointerException` into your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException while reading multiple files from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810338/nullpointerexception-while-reading-multiple-files-from-a-directory)

Comment: question is exactly like that but it just skipped null file . bt i hava a file in that folder

Comment: which line is producing the exception ?

Comment: Printing the path doesn't tells you if it correct or not, it may contain character not printed causing the path to be wrong. For example it's something that append [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813491/empty-file-constructor-is-neither-file-nor-directory)

Comment: for loop line is producing exception

Comment: So it's the duplicate. Read the answer of the question I posted. You need to check if `listOfFiles` is null - if so, an I/O error probably happened. The folder might not exist or it might not be a folder - or you may not have rights to access it, etc.

Comment: folder is there . i checked it  How to know if i have the right to access . the folder is inside the webapp folder. so it  should be accessable by server right?

Comment: i give directly th path like D:\\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\\webapps\\JaasLogin\\user-files\\Antony by escaping the single \ with \\ . it worked but i it give error when it is a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: "for loop line is producing exception " - mark with a comment which line throws the exception. Also post the output you get

Answer (score 0):

As Javadoc for [File.listFiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) states:

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or
>   if an I/O error occurs.

So in order to prevent NPE do something like this:

```
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    if (listOfFiles != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Could not read " + folder.getName());
    }
```